# what informtations pas the evt event object

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with an excercise, you can see the code below.
I dont understand then event object evt, and also the book is not clear about that.
Example in the code why it use showMessage(evt) and  alert(evt.data.message), it is necessary??
THanks for help
Frank

```js
var linkVar = {message:'Hello from a link'};
var pVar = {message: 'Hello from a p'};
function showMessage(evt) {
  alert(evt.data.message);
  }
 $('a')on('mouseover' , linkVar, showMessage);
 $('p')on('mouseover' , pVar, showMessage);
```

Comment: **evt** ... will represent an element inside the function to apply the actions; then later this will allow you pass any value at the time you execute the function and bind the events to it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help you have running code as an example:

```
// Variable definitions
var linkVar = {message:'Hello from a link'};
var pVar = {message: 'Hello from a p'};

// What to do on mouseover event on which elements and what to call when that happens
$('a').on('mouseover' , linkVar, showMessage);
$('p').on('mouseover' , pVar, showMessage);

// Function definition (it will be called everytime cursor mouseovers over elements A and P)
function showMessage(evt) {
  alert(evt.data.message);
}
```

From here, you have the [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method which will say:

data
Type: Anything
Data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event is triggered.

so anything will be passed as event.**data** so to get to the field you need you will use evt.data.message

Hope this clears your confusion.

Here it is in a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vdhobqny/

Comment: pratically evt.data.message contains inside the string of variable depending on the over  p or a.
Couse the evt record the event in this case over on p or over on a.
But data?? what is that?

Comment: Correct, and that variable is passed into the mouseover function (take notice that one variable is passed to A elements, and a different one is passed to P elements, hence the different message when you hover over one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The last thins but in evt.data.message data what is? why is it there??

Comment: Is just what the framework defines. If you click on the ON link (in the answer) you will see that the documentation creates that definition for us, so every time the framework deals with that method the parameter will be called like that. It is kind of hard to get your head around it but just take it as it is and you will get used to it.